# incrementing a word ahead in 2d array using pointers

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program to read a piece of text and put it in the correct grammar. All punctuation marks and newlines in the text are preceded by a ':'. One of the functions of my program is adding spaces between words that are read from the text file. However, I don't want it to do that all the time. Since ':.' marking the end of a sentence is a new word and not part of the previous word, it'll add a space between the last word and the period.

"... at the zoo ."

Instead of this:

"... at the zoo."

I'm trying to write a function that looks at the next word in the array to see if it's a colon.
Here's what I tried, among other things:

```
int isColon(char madLib[][256], int numWords)
{
    numWords++;
    char* k = madLib[numWords];
    if (*k == ':')
    {
        cout << "{*k}";
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Here is the output: {╠}

Without incrementing the counter (numWords), it displays the first letter without any problem.
However, I need it to look to the next word.

What do I do? Any suggestions?

Here is the code that actually displays the text:

```
int readFile(const char fileName[])
{
    ifstream fin(fileName);
    //if error when opening file, it will return true
    if (fin.fail())
    {
        return true;
    }
    char madLib[256][256];
    int numWords = 0;

    while (fin >> madLib[numWords])
    {
        bool isSpace = true;
        bool noPrint = false;
        char* k = madLib[numWords];
        while (*k)
        {
            if (*k == ':')
            {
                k++;
                if (*k == '!')
                    cout << endl,
                    isSpace = false;
                else if (*k == '.')
                    cout << ".";
                else if (*k == ',')
                    cout << ", ";
                else if (*k == '<')
                    cout << "\"",
                    isSpace = false;
                else if (*k == '>')
                    cout << "\" ";
                else
                    displayArray(madLib, numWords),
                    noPrint = true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (noPrint == false)
                    cout << *k;
            }
            k++;
        }
        if (isSpace == true && isColon(madLib, numWords) == false)
            cout << " ";
        noPrint = false;
        numWords++;
    }
    fin.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where in your code are you displaying anything? Right now I just see `"{*k}"` being output. "I need it to look to the next word" You need *what* to look to the next word? The function? The function only checks if a particular... `char*` starts with `:`?

Comment: good question. The code that displays the revised "grammar improved" text is in a different function. I'll edit the post so you can see if that helps. @John

Comment: You need to put braces round multi line if statements. Your code would be simpler with a switch statement rather than a long if/else chain

Comment: will do, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion, the main problem is that you are still working in complete C-Style mode. With all errors that result out of that.

You are using pointers and C-Style arrays. Recommendation: Do **not** and never use raw pointers for owned memory in C++.

Recommendation: Do **not** use C-style arrays in C++ (or only, if you know what your are doing).

Btw: You are using the wrong syntax for passing an 2d-array (which you should not use in the first place) to your functions. The array is decaying to a pointer.

You have huge risks for out of bounds problems using your magic numbers 256.

But your specific problem is resulting from a wrong design. You read a word, and then, before you have read the next word, you already check this none existing word.

Look at your code. You are doing `fin >> something`, then operate on this something, then you are calling your subfunction to check the next word. But this has not yet been read.

So, the recommendation is: At first read all words into your array, and then, afterwards, check your array content.

I hope this helps